# "Render" an SVG polygon with a pattern fill

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'd like to be able to use svg patterns to fill a polygon, then export the result of the pattern fill as individual svg paths/polygons etc.

So I'd like to start with this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="300" height="130">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="ozmkp" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="20" height="20">
      <path d="M 10, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
    </pattern>
</defs>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="#ff0066" x="20" y="20" style="
      fill: url('#ozmkp');
  "></rect>
</svg>
```

Then end up with this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="300" height="130">
  <path d="M 20, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 40, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 60, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 80, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 100, 0 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>

  <path d="M 20, 20 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 40, 20 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 60, 20 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 80, 20 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 100, 20 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>

  <path d="M 20, 40 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 40, 40 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 60, 40 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 80, 40 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 100, 40 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>

  <path d="M 20, 60 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 40, 60 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 60, 60 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 80, 60 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 100, 60 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>

  <path d="M 20, 80 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 40, 80 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 60, 80 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 80, 80 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
  <path d="M 100, 80 l 0, 20" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges" stroke="#343434" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
</svg>
```

Is there a library that does this, or an extensible way to do this with more complex patterns?